# How do people publish books in Esperanto?

Tags: literature, writing

Are there official publishers who work with Esperanto authors? Or is there some sort of semi-vanity publishing arrangement for most Esperanto works?

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for Esperanto books

- Mondial http://www.librejo.com/

Open to all languages:

- Createspace https://www.createspace.com/
- IngramSpark http://www.ingramspark.com/
- Gutenberg self publishing http://www.gutenberg.us/

Answer (score 3):

One of the more active (though somewhat local) publishers is Espero - http://www.espero.sk

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking at just publishing e-books, there are many online (non-Esperanto-specific) services you can create and sell your books through.

Some of these are:

- Leanpub - http://leanpub.com/
- Softcover - http://softcover.io/

It's mostly technical books that get sold through these platforms, but they do support non-technical books in any language. Leanpub specifically has Esperanto as a language option you can select when creating a book.

Answer (score 0):

One good site to publish ebooks in Esperanto is [Smashwords](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/631648). They will upload the book to many other retailers on your behalf. Sadly they can’t be sold in the Kindle store because Amazon currently rejects books in Esperanto.